# Некорректное построение БД T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Доброго времени суток. Возник вопрос по проектированию таблицы. Третий день не могу решить, не заходит и всё тут) Надеюсь на вашу помощь.
Запрос должен вернуть количество рабочих часов для определенного сотрудника @IDEmpl в промежуток времени между @FirstTime & @SecondTime.

[image: База данных]

Если делать так, то работает только для графика с id = 1, т.е. с рабочим временем в 8 часов, т.к. в таблице праздниках написано -8 часов. А если взять рабочий график в 10 рабочих часов, то этот способ не подходит.

```
-- Диапозон времени, за котрый считаем рабочие часы
DECLARE @FirstTime as datetime = '2014-04-01'
DECLARE @SecondTime as datetime = '2014-04-30'
-- id работника, нужно для сортировки его рабочих дат
DECLARE @IDEmpl AS int = 6
-- Расчет времени рабочего дня, согласно графику
DECLARE @ScheduleTime as int =      (
    Select  DATEDIFF (HH, StartTime, EndTime)
    From        Schedules AS Sch
        RIGHT JOIN Employees AS Empl ON Sch.IDSchedule = Empl.IDSchedules
    Where   IDEmployee = @IDEmpl    )

Select  IDEmployee, LastName + ' ' + FirstName AS Name, sum(@ScheduleTime - ISNULL(H.MinusHours,0)) AS [Hours Of Work]
From        Employees AS E
        JOIN Calendar AS C ON C.Date BETWEEN E.HireDate AND ISNULL(E.DismissalDate,GETDATE())
        LEFT JOIN Holidays AS H ON H.HDate = C.Date
Where E.IDEmployee=@IDEmpl AND C.Date BETWEEN @FirstTime AND @SecondTime
Group by    IDEmployee, LastName, FirstName;
```

От сюда, как правильно спроектировать таблицу выходных, чтобы в запросе рабочее время зависело от графика?

Comment: Мне кажется тут либо в таблицу `Holidays` добавить `IDSchedule`, от которого будет зависеть `MinusHours` (8 для `IDSchedule=1`, 10 для `IDSchedule=2`). Либо вообще не смотреть на `MinusHours` в этой таблице (у вас там всюду 8, или возможны и другие значения?), а просто суммировать рабочее время по диапазону дней, исключив выходные/праздники.

Comment: Там может быть либо -8 часов, то есть полный выходной, либо -1 час, т.е. сокращенный день

Comment: Тогда видимо добавлять `IDSchedule` в `Holidays`. Это даст также возможность для разных графиков иметь разный набор выходных (например кто-то работает в праздники, кто-то - нет, кто-то часть дней работает, часть - отдыхает). Хотя... можно в `Holidays` вместо `MinusHours` завести флаг - полный выходной, или сокращенный день, в зависимости от него вычитать для этого дня либо час, либо полную продолжительность. Но это если только два варианта (-1 и -8/10), также этот вариант не даст возможности иметь разный набор выходных. В общем, смотрите что вам больше подходит.

Comment: "можно в Holidays вместо MinusHours завести флаг. Но это если только два варианта (-1 и -8/10)" Варианта два, думаю так и сделаю. не подскажите ещё, пожалуйста, новичку. Это через if делать, или case? Или в Where как-то можно прописать ?

Comment: Cкорее всего `case`, либо `iif`(появился начиная с SqlServer 2012).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Спасибо @i-one за ответ. правильное решение теперь выглядит так. Для меня оно полностью подходит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: SQL-код лучше текстом вставьте (с картинки текст не скопируешь, а вдруг кому-то ещё пригодится).